# Padé approximationi of polynomial

Tags: power-series, approximation, pade-approximation

Following [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant), I'm trying to compute the $[1/1]$-Padé approximation of $f(x)=x^2$. It should be of the form $\frac{a+bx}{1+cx}$, but this is either zero or a power series with a non-zero constant or linear term. In any case, it cannot approximate $x^2$ with an error of order $x^3$. Am I missing an assumption?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this but I don't think the Padé approximant always exists. You see the Wikipedia article using the phrase "*when* it exists..."

Comment: Good point. In my opinion, this should be emphasized much more in the wikipedia article. Especially the computation section gives the impression that it always works. This is also very nebulous in the first volume of [Baker, Graves-Moris]. On p. 3 they write "Thus (1.6) and (1.7) normally determine the Padé numerator and denominator"

Comment: In which interval do you want to approximate the function ? The Pade-approximation is usually only good within a small interval.

Comment: @Peter Wikipedia says the Padé approximation is uniquely determined. I think it does not depend on an interval.

Comment: The error of the approximation however will depend on where we use it. Usually , this is done near $0$. Even in the existing cases , the approximation gets soon useless if the values grow.

Comment: You are correct : it is unique as a Taylor series is.

Comment: @Peter. The Padé approximant is unique just as the Taylor series is.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is not what I asked. I never claimed that it is not unique.

Comment: But do we agree that the error term should be of order $x^3$?

Comment: @Peter. Sorry for misunderstanding then ! Cheers :-)

Comment: You can get an approximation in this form. See [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/svsrqlxuom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us seek a general expression for the $[1/1]$ Padé approximant in terms of derivatives. We have

$f(x)=\dfrac{a+bx}{1+cx}+O(x^3)$

and expand using the geometric series formula to get

$f(x)=a+(b-ac)x+(ac^2-bc)x^2+O(x^3)$

So matching with the Taylor series

$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12f''(0)x^2+O(x^3)$

we get the system

$a=f(0)$

$b-ac=f'(0)\implies b=f'(0)+cf(0)$

$ac^2-bc=\frac12f''(0)\implies -f'(0)c=\frac12f''(0)$

$\therefore c=-\dfrac{f''(0)}{2f'(0)}, b=f'(0)-\dfrac{f(0)f''(0)}{2f'(0)},a=f(0).$

It becomes apparent that a singularity occurs when $f'(0)=0$. That is where your problem came with $f(x)=x^2$.

If your aim is to practice generating Padé approximants, choose a function that avoids this problem. For instance, with $f(x)=x^2+x$ whose derivative at $0$ is nonzero you should smoothly get $x/(1-x)$.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe the "right" question is: *When* does the Padé approximation exist?

Answer (score 1):

I give a necessary and sufficient criterion for the existence of a formal Padé $[m/n]$-approximation assuming that $f$ has a Taylor series, say $f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kX^k$. Let $\beta=\sum b_kX^k$ and $\gamma=\sum c_kX^k$ be the polynomials of the approximation with degree $\le m$ and $\le n$ respectively and with $c_0=1$.
Then $f\gamma\equiv\beta\pmod{X^{m+n}}$ translates to the linear system $\sum_{i=0}^ka_{k-i}c_i=b_k$ for $k=0,\ldots,m+n$.
Since $b_k=0$ for $k>m$ and $c_0=1$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{k-i}c_i=-a_k$$
for $k=m+1,\ldots,m+n$.
The Padé $[m/n]$-approximation exists if and only if this system has a  solution (the $b_k$ are determined by $\sum_{i=0}^ka_{k-i}c_i=b_k$ for $k=0,\ldots,m$).
For convenience let $a_k=0$ for $k<0$. Define $A:=(a_{m+i-j})_{i,j=1}^{n}$ and $b:=-(a_{m+i})_{i=1}^n$. Then $(c_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a solution of $Ax=b$. By linear algebra, the Padé $[m/n]$-approximation exists if and only if $A$ and the extended matrix $(A|b)$ have the same rank.

In the special case of the question we have $n=m=1$, $a_0=a_1=0$ and $A=(0)$, but $b=(-1)$. In general, $A$ is a Toeplitz matrix, which is invertible for instance, if $a_0=\ldots=a_{m-1}=0$ and $a_m\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to find a rational approximation (for $0 \leq x \leq t$) minimizing the norm
$$\Phi=\int_0^t  \left(x^2-\frac{a+b x}{1+c x}\right)^2\,dx$$ which is
$$\Phi=\frac{2 (b c-1) (a c-b) \log (c t+1)}{c^4}+\frac{t (2 a c+b (b
   c-2))}{c^3}-\frac{(b-a c)^2}{c^3 (c t+1)}+$$ $$\frac{(b-a
   c)^2}{c^3}+\frac{t^2 (b-a c)}{c^2}-\frac{2 b t^3}{3
   c}+\frac{t^5}{5}$$ Computing the partial derivatives
$$c^3\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}=\frac{c t \left(c \left(2 a c-2 b-c t^2+t\right)+2\right)}{c
   t+1}+2 (b c-1) \log (c t+1)\tag 1$$
$$3c^4\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial b}=6 \left(a c^2-2 b c+1\right) \log (c t+1)+$$ $$\frac{c t (c (-6 a
   c+6 b (c t+2)+t (c t (1-2 c t)-3))-6)}{c t+1}\tag 2$$ So, for a given value of $t$,we have the expressions of $a(c)$ and $b(c)$  (two linear equations for two variables).

So, what is left is to solve for a given $t$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial c}=0$$

This is a monster but using numerical methods, there is no major problem.

Trying for $t=2$ and making the numbers rational
$$a \sim -\frac{91}{452} \qquad b \sim \frac{411}{439} \qquad c \sim -\frac{55}{184}\qquad \Phi=9.65\times 10^{-3}$$ which is not totally ridiculous.

At the midpoint $(x=1)$, the approximation gives $\frac{6707858}{6399303}=1.04822$.

Comment: This is not Padé approximation.

Comment: @OscarLanzi. I know ! There IS no one. This IS juste a way toi make something looking like

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have accepted Oscar's answer, but of course the actual answer is in Qiaochu's comment.